# LDAP binding a user in a domain on a different server and domain than the server hosting the application

Tags: c#, ldap, webapi, .net-7.0

I have .net 7 application with domain authorization. The application is hosted on IIS where the server is in domain "D1", domain server d1.com. When I try to login with user (login / pass) that exist in domain "D1" everything is fine (the same domain user and server). But when i try bind a user that exist on another server in another domain "B1" server b1.com I get an error like:

```
A local error occurred.
```

My binding code:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
LdapDirectoryIdentifier id = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(server);

using (LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(id, credentials, AuthType.Kerberos))
{
    connection.SessionOptions.Sealing = true;
    connection.SessionOptions.Signing = true;

    try
    {
        connection.Bind();
    }
    catch (LdapException iex)
    {
         // log
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         // log
    }
```

The test account have admin rights, and domains have a trust relationship. I can ping domain 2 server from 1.
Do you have any idea whats wrong?

//Edit

Instead of LdapConnection I used DirectoryEntry and it worked but I don't know why.

```
string path = $"LDAP://{domainOptions.Server}";
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path, userName, password))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
    {
        adSearch.Filter = $"(sAMAccountName={userName})";
        SearchResult? adSearchResult = adSearch.FindOne();

        if (adSearchResult != null)
        {
            // login ok
        }
        else
        {
            // login not ok
        }
    }
}
```